# Fragment sliding over Dialog Fragment

Tags: android

I have three fragments - Fragment 1 ,Fragment 2 and Fragment 3. Fragment 2 is a DialogFragment.The flow needed is
Fragment 2 slide over Fragment 1
Fragment 2 will show some list
On selecting an item in the list Fragment 3 will be loaded.

On Pressing back button from Fragment 3 it should show Fragment 2 
On pressing back button from Fragment 2 should show Fragment 1

I want Fragment2 to slide up from bottom over Fragment 1.So I used Fragment 2 as a DialogFragment.Fragment 2 should cover the entire window.

On selecting an item from Fragment 2 will call Fragment 3.Fragment 3 is shown in view only if Fragment 2 is removed or dismissed.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: *How to solve this issue?* - This isn't an "issue", it's how the system handles the transactions you make. To solve it you manually dismiss the `DialogFragment`.